# Issue compiling c++ source

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, trinitycore

I have a problem compiling a C++ program and I tried to find the issue and solve it but currently I wasn't able to find the source of the problem. I will appreciate if someone give me a hand :)

The error given is: (compiling under Centos 6.3 with gcc 4.4.7)

```
In file included from /home/server/Sources/MOP/MistCore/src/server/scripts/PrecompiledHeaders/ScriptPCH.h:25,
                 from /home/server/Sources/MOP/MistCore/src/server/game/Anticheat/AnticheatMgr.h:7,
                 from /home/server/Sources/MOP/MistCore/src/server/game/Anticheat/AnticheatData.h:4,
                 from /home/server/Sources/MOP/MistCore/src/server/game/Anticheat/AnticheatData.cpp:1:
/home/server/Sources/MOP/MistCore/src/server/game/Spells/SpellScript.h: In constructor ‘AuraScript::AuraScript()’:
/home/server/Sources/MOP/MistCore/src/server/game/Spells/SpellScript.h:619: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<Aura>::shared_ptr(NULL)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:1263: note: candidates are: std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&&) [with _Tp = Aura]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:1238: note:                 std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr() [with _Tp = Aura]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:1236: note:                 std::shared_ptr<Aura>::shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<Aura>&)
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/Anticheat/AnticheatData.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Files:

- `SpellScript.cpp`: http://pastebin.com/Cam59CWt
- `SpellScript.h`: http://pastebin.com/XYp6pSf9

Yeah, it's a long piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), `std::shared_ptr` was introduced in C++11.

Compiling C++11 with GCC requires it's version 4.7 or later.

Note that MistCore is based on the TrinityCore, that instead of using a C++11 specific define named `AuraPtr` uses a simple `Aura*` pointer. Reverting this to the original state should work just as it used to in the original project.

You can simply edit `/src/server/game/SharedPtrs/SharedPtrs.h` and undo the need of `std::shared_ptr` by replacing the defines with simple pointers. No guarantee that it will solve all problems though. [Exemple](https://gist.github.com/Havenard/babbfa6c789a0f1a1201).

Comment: compiles with errors still...

so if i use gcc 4.7 should fix it? gonna try

Comment: Yeah, perhaps upgrading your compiler is a better option since the extension of the C++11 specific changes is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

You can specifi the flag using -std=c++11